# An equivalence of Markov property

Tags: markov-chains

Let $S$ be a countable set and $(X_n)$ an $S$-valued discrete Markov chain. Then
$$
\mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_0=x_0] = \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n]
$$
for all $x_0, \ldots, x_{n+1} \in S$. This is called the *Markov* property. I would like to prove that

> **Theorem**
> $$
> \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_m=x_m] = \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n]
> $$
> for all $m \le n$ and $x_0, \ldots, x_{n+1} \in S$.

Could you confirm if my below understanding is correct?

---

**Proof** We have
$$
\begin{align}
& \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_m=x_m] \\
= & \sum_{x_{m-1}, \ldots, x_0 \in S} \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_0=x_0] \mathbb P[X_{m-1} = x_{m-1}, \ldots, X_0=x_0 | X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_m=x_m] \\
= & \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n] \sum_{x_{m-1}, \ldots, x_0 \in S}  \mathbb P[X_{m-1} = x_{m-1}, \ldots, X_0=x_0 | X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_m=x_m] \\
=& \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n].
\end{align}
$$

Above,

- the first equality follows from the law of total conditional probability,
- the second one follows from Markov property, and
- the third one follows from the fact that $\sum_n \mathbb P[A_n|B] = 1$ if $(A_n)$ is a collection of pairwise disjoints events whose union is the whole sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo in the theorem: $X_n = x_1$ should be $X_n = x_n$. Your proof is correct.

Another proof by double expectation formula:
$$
\begin{align}
P[X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n, ..., X_m = x_m] &= E\left[P\left[X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n, ..., X_m = x_m\right] | X_{m-1}, ..., X_0\right] \\
&= EP[X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n] \\
&= P[X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you explain how to get the second equality?

Comment: @Akira $ P[X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n, ..., X_m = x_m | X_{m-1}, ..., X_0] = P[X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_n = x_n]$