# Another equivalence of Markov property

Tags: markov-chains

Let $S$ be a countable state space and $(X_n)$ an $S$-valued discrete Markov chain. Then
$$
\mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_0=x_0] = \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n]
$$
for all $x_0, \ldots, x_{n+1} \in S$. This is called the *Markov* property. Previously, I proved that

> [Theorem 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611106/an-equivalence-of-markov-property)
> $$
> \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n, \ldots, X_m=x_m] = \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_n = x_n]
> $$
> for all $m \le n$ and $x_m, \ldots, x_{n+1} \in S$.

Now I would like to generalize it, i.e.,

> **Theorem 2**
> $$
> \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_M = x_M, \ldots, X_m=x_m] = \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_M = x_M]
> $$
> for all $m \le M \le n$ and $x_m, \ldots, x_{n+1} \in S$.

Could you confirm if my below understanding is correct?

---

**Proof** We proceed by backward induction on $M$. By **Theorem 1**, the statement holds for the base case $M=n$. Let it hold for $M$. Let's prove that it holds for $M-1$. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
& \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_{M-1} = x_{M-1}, \ldots, X_m=x_m]  \\
=& \sum_{x\in S} \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_M = x,X_{M-1} = x_{M-1}, \ldots, X_m=x_m]  \mathbb P [X_{M} = x_{M} |X_{M-1} = x_{M-1}, \ldots, X_m=x_m] \\
=& \sum_{x\in S} \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} | X_M = x,X_{M-1} = x_{M-1}]  \mathbb P [X_{M} = x_{M} |X_{M-1} = x_{M-1}] \\
=& \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_{M-1} = x_{M-1}].
\end{align*}
$$

Above,

- the first and the third equalities follows from the law of total conditional probability.
- the second one follows from inductive hypothesis and Markov property.

This completes the proof.

Comment: In Theorem 2 let us check first if the statement has any chance. Something should happen for all $m,n$ with $m\le n$ i suppose, and then for each two such fixed values for all possible $M$ between $m$ and $n$. If this is so, let me please fix $m=M=0$, and take some $n$ gigger $2023$ say. Than Theorem 2 claims that $$\Bbb P[X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}\ |\ X_0=x_0]=\Bbb P[X_{n+1}\ |\ X_n=x_n]\ ,$$and i have doubts.  E.g. $X$ may start in $x_0$, i.e. $X_0=x_0$ happens with probability 1. Then i can imagine a process (random walk, step one) never passing from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$ in 1 step. But in $n$ steps...

Comment: @dan_fulea Ah it's a typo. It should be $\mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_M = x_M, \ldots, X_m=x_m] = \mathbb P [X_{n+1} = x_{n+1} |X_M = x_M]$.

Comment: Yes, it is ok now.

Comment: @dan_fulea Thank you so much for your verification!